# Radiobutton IF condition not executed in Javascript in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, radio-button, radiobuttonlist

This is my code:

asp.net:

```
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td class="td1" colspan="2" style="width:100%;text-align:center;border-top-left-radius:10px;border-top-right-radius:10px">Make Payment</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="td1" title="Payment Mode">Payment Mode:</td>
                    <td class="td2">
                        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblpaymentmode" runat="server" CssClass="lbidname" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" ToolTip="Select Payment Mode" OnSelectedIndexChanged="rblpaymentmode_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="True" CausesValidation="True">
                            <asp:ListItem>Cheque</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Cash</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:RadioButtonList>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="td1" title="Member Name">Member:</td>
                    <td class="td2">
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlmember" runat="server" CssClass="ddl" ToolTip="Select Member">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="td1" title="Particular Type">Particular Type:<br />
                        <br />
                        <asp:Label ID="lbenterdetails" runat="server" Text="Enter Details:" ToolTip="Enter Details:" Visible="False"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td class="td2">
                        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblparticulartype" runat="server" CssClass="lbidname" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" OnSelectedIndexChanged="rblparticulartype_SelectedIndexChanged" ToolTip="Select Particular Type" AutoPostBack="True" CausesValidation="True">
                            <asp:ListItem Selected="True">Yearly Lawaazam</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Other</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:RadioButtonList>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtotherparticulartype" runat="server" CssClass="textbox" ToolTip="Enter Details" Width="90%" Visible="False"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                </tr>                    
                <tr>
                    <td class="td1" title="Cheque Date">Cheque Date:</td>
                    <td class="td2">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtchequedate" runat="server" CssClass="textbox" Width="90%" ToolTip="Select Cheque Date"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:CalendarExtender runat="server" ID="cetxtchequedate" CssClass="cal_Theme1" PopupPosition="Right" TargetControlID="txtchequedate" Format="yyyy-MM-dd"></asp:CalendarExtender>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="td1" title="Cheque No.">Cheque No.:</td>
                    <td class="td2">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtchequeno" runat="server" CssClass="textbox" Width="90%" ToolTip="Enter Cheque No."></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="td1" title="Bank Name">Bank Name:</td>
                    <td class="td2">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtbankname" runat="server" CssClass="textbox" Width="90%" ToolTip="Enter Bank Name"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="td1" title="Branch Name">Branch Name:</td>
                    <td class="td2">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtbranchname" runat="server" CssClass="textbox" Width="90%" ToolTip="Enter Branch Name"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="td1">
                        <asp:Label ID="lbpaymentdate" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td class="td2">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtpaymentdate" runat="server" CssClass="textbox" Width="90%" ToolTip="Enter Clearance Date"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:CalendarExtender runat="server" ID="cetxtclearancedate" CssClass="cal_Theme1" PopupPosition="Right" TargetControlID="txtpaymentdate" Format="yyyy-MM-dd"></asp:CalendarExtender>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="td1" title="Amount">Amount:</td>
                    <td class="td2">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtamount" runat="server" CssClass="textbox" Width="90%" ToolTip="Enter Amount"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="td2" colspan="2" style="width:100%;text-align:center;background-color:#FFF6C1">
                        <asp:Panel ID="pnlchequeimage" runat="server" Visible="false">
                            <p style="padding-top:5px">Upload a cheque image to <a href="http://www.tinypic.com" target="_blank">TinyPic.com</a> &amp; paste the image url in the textbox below.</p> 
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtchequeimage" CssClass="textbox" Width="60%" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                            <br />
                            <br />
                        </asp:Panel>
                    </td>                        
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="td1" colspan="2" style="width:100%;text-align:center;padding-bottom:10px;padding-top:10px;border-bottom-left-radius:10px;border-bottom-right-radius:10px">
                        <asp:Button ID="btnmakepayment" runat="server" CssClass="button" Text="Make Payment" OnClientClick="return validate()" ToolTip="Make Payment" Width="120px" />
                    </td>                        
                </tr>
            </table>
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
    function validate() {
 if (document.getElementById("<%=rblparticulartype.ClientID%>").value == "Other") {
            if (document.getElementById("<%=txtotherparticulartype.ClientID%>").value=="") {
                alert("Please enter details");
                document.getElementById("<%=txtotherparticulartype.ClientID%>").focus();
                return false;
         }              
    }
}
</script>
<br/>
```

I want to check, if radiobutton "Other" is selected then the textbox "txtotherparticulartype" is not empty on submission

but it does not go into the loop of Radiobutton if condition

Please Help!!!

Comment: Post the rendered HTML and script (view-source)

Answer (score 0):

Some corrections and advice:

First you set `visible` to false for `txtotherparticulartype` change it to `true`

Second you have a `radionbutton` list so it's children will get `id` like this:

`rblparticulartype_0` refers to the id of the first list item;

`rblparticulartype_1` refers to the id of the second
so you can try this to get value of checked (Doesn't test by myself):

```
var value = document.getElemenById("rblparticulartype_0");
```

Another way is that you can access to each `ListItem` of radio buttons using `getElementsByName` and index like this:

```
var check = document.getElementsByName('rblparticulartype')[1].checked;
```

BTW you code should be like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function validate() { 
        var check = document.getElementsByName('rblparticulartype')[1].checked;
            if (check == true) {
                var value = document.getElementById("<%=txtotherparticulartype.ClientID %>").value;
                if (value == "") {
                    alert("Please enter details");
                    document.getElementById("<%=txtotherparticulartype.ClientID%>").focus();
                    return false;
                }
            }
        } 
</script>
```

or at the end should be like this:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function validate() {
        var radioButtons = document.getElementsByName("rblparticulartype"); 
        for (var x = 0; x < radioButtons.length; x++) {
            if (radioButtons[x].checked && radioButtons[x].value == "Other") {
                var value = document.getElementById("<%=txtotherparticulartype.ClientID %>").value;
                if (value == "") {
                    alert("Please enter details");
                    document.getElementById("<%=txtotherparticulartype.ClientID%>").focus();
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

I have tested both of above codes they works perfectly.

Hope will help.